# Binary tree operations Main function

Tags: java

I am not getting the o/p for the code below. Is my countinternalnodes is correct? What are the changes i need to make in the main function to get o/p.I am not getting error when i run the code. How to enter the variable to the countinternalnodes function.

```
class Node 
 {
    int data;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int item) 
    {
        data = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
  }
public class BinaryTree {
          Node root;
         public void insert(int id){
        Node newNode = new Node(id);
        if(root==null){
            root = newNode;
            return;
        }
        Node current = root;
        Node parent = null;
        while(true){
            parent = current;
            if(id<current.data){                
                current = current.left;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.left = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else{
                current = current.right;
                if(current==null){
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public int getLeafCount() 
    {
        return getLeafCount(root);
    }
public int getLeafCount(Node node) 
    {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
            return 1;
        else
            return getLeafCount(node.left) + getLeafCount(node.right);
    }

 public int numNodesIn(Node v) {
        if (v == null) return 0;
        return 1 + numNodesIn(v.left) + numNodesIn(v.right);
    }

 public int numEdgesIn(Node v) {
        return v == null? 0 : numNodesIn(v) - 1;
    }

 public void display(Node root){

        if(root!=null){

            System.out.print(" " + root.data);
            display(root.left);
            display(root.right);
            }
        }

int countinternalnodes(Node e) 
  { 
      if(e == root)
      {
            return 0;
      }
     if(e.left == null && e.right == null)
     {
        return 1; 
     }
     else
     {
        return countinternalnodes(e.left)+countinternalnodes(e.right);

     }

  }

public int maxDepth(Node root) {
    if(root==null)
        return 0;

    int leftDepth = maxDepth(root.left);
    int rightDepth = maxDepth(root.right);

    int bigger = Math.max(leftDepth, rightDepth);

    return bigger+1;
}
 // Main Function

public static void main (String[] args)
{
  BinaryTree b = new BinaryTree();

  b.insert(3);b.insert(0);
  b.insert(1);b.insert(4);b.insert(6);b.insert(2);b.insert(10);b.insert(9);
  b.insert(20);b.insert(25);b.insert(15);b.insert(16);


  System.out.println("Original Tree : ");

  b.display(b.root);
  System.out.println("count internal nodes : ");
  b.countinternalnodes(b.root);// part is not working
  b.maxDepth(b.root);
  b.getLeafCount();


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you are not printing the value, don't know if you forgot to paste it here or what, but you need to do this:

`System.out.println(b.countinternalnodes(b.root));`

Second: the value is wrong. You are passing `b.root` to this method and then there is immediately a check if the passed argument is root (and in this case it is) so it returns `0`, and I don't think that's what you want.

Third: the problem of counting when the value actually has children. You are doing `return countinternalnodes(e.left) + countinternalnodes(e.right);`, but you are forgetting about that value itself, so you need to add `1` to this. Generally I changed your method to this:

```java
int countinternalnodes(Node e) {
  if (e == null)
    return 0;
  if (e.left == null && e.right == null)
    return 1;
  else
    return 1 + countinternalnodes(e.left) + countinternalnodes(e.right);
}
```

Not sure if that's what you wanted, from the name `countInternal` I guess that the output should not count root, but it does, just subtract `1` if that's the case.

I didn't look at other parts of your code since that's not what the question is about.